# Notifications won't push to real device

Tags: android, notifications

I was following along to TheNewBoston Android App Development for Beginners - 63 - Styles video for pushing notifications.
The app works perfectly in Android Studio's emulator, but when I run the app on my phone, the notifications won't show up.

Is there a reason notifications work on the emulator, but not an actual device?

Comment: What is the Android version of your device?

Answer (score 0):

in some devices like Huawei you need to make your app as protected app to use notification feature. you can use below code to detect Device Model and make decision to go to the protected app setting.

```
    String PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

    if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(PhoneModel)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after I posted the question I figured out what the problem was. I updated my phone to Oreo recently and was trying to use the old way (the way thenewboston did it inside his videos). Apparently for android Oreo you have to code notifications with channels, the old way for notifications is not compatible with Oreo.